# Mathematical and special characters on mysql

Tags: mysql

I need my mysql database to accept characters like the following:

```
≈ ≅ ≆ ≠ ⊂ ⊃ ⊄ ⊅ ⊆ ⊇ ⊈ ⊉ ⋅ ∥ ∣ √ ∛ ∜ ∞ ∓ ± ∑ ∌ ∋ ∈ ∉ ∅ ∃ ∄ ∀ ∁ ∩ ∪ ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁿ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ 
₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎ → ← ↔ ↚ ↛ ⇆ ⇋ ⇌ Γ Δ Θ Λ  Π Φ Ω α β γ  δ ε η θ λ μ ℳ π ρ σ τ φ  Ϙ ϙ Ϝ ϝ Ϻ ϻ ϼ Τ
```

Does somebody know how to achieve it?

[EDIT]: I tried using UTF-8:

```
ALTER SCHEMA `acessoed_portal_student` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
   COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE  `question` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

 ALTER TABLE  `question` CHANGE `description` `description`
  TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE  `question_response` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 

ALTER TABLE  `question_response` CHANGE `description_response` `description_response`
  TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: what is your tried code?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: @MahdiParsa Updated question with code... tried character set utf-8, collation utf8_general_ci

Comment: @MarcoA: what is your php contention code ? do set chart set after connect?

Comment: @MahdiParsa Actually, I'm not using PHP... I ran that script connected to the database directly in command-line... mysql version is 5.6

Comment: @RobertHarvey How do I find out which one to use? Added charset script used...

Comment: after you connect to mysql before insert data send this query `set names utf8;` that mysql accept uft-8 chars in next queries.

Comment: You problem solved or not?

Comment: I found out that manual inserts work fine... In-app inserts are the problem. I'm using java, when/if I figure out a solution, I'll post it. Thanks @MahdiParsa

Comment: @MarcoA., there's a never ending issue with java web apps and the encoding as webapps are not configured by default to be UTF8. Please read this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) about how to default be UTF8. You'll need to configure/create a filter that sets the encoding if the client (browser) doesn't send one.

Comment: @Augusto I'm using glassfish... Just found this code <glassfish-web-app>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
</glassfish-web-app>, about to test it

Comment: @Augusto Did not work...

Comment: Also tried externalContext.setRequestCharacterEncoding("UTF8");. Didn't work as well. I'm gonna implement as suggested by Simone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about html encoding? You can Write the symbol with the corresponding Escape sequence For example ∞ is the infinite symbol.

Comment: Interesting workaround... Still trying to figure if it's possible to do the insert. If it's not actually possible, I'll try your solution!